# Select all non-blank cells and associated Rows

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been searching for well over 3 hours for a formula or vba solution for this and for some reason can not find anything.

I need something to look at a column, find all the non-blank cells, and output them elsewhere.
Here is a small example table of the data:

[image: Original data]

And here is what I would like to have outputed:

[image: Output table]

I've found many solutions most of which have been combinations of =value and =match but I either get zero results, or the results have blanks in the column that should never have blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this macro

```
Sub findBlankCells()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
'change the sheet to whatever name sheet you have
ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'didn't chose A since it seems like you have more blank values there
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'j represents the row to copy to
j = 1
'loop through all the rows
For i = 1 To lastrow
'only copy to I and J column if both do not equal blank
If ws.Cells(i, "A") <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then
    ws.Cells(j, "I") = ws.Cells(i, "A")
    ws.Cells(j, "J") = ws.Cells(i, "B")
    'increase j if the statement is true to go on to the next row to copy to
    j = j + 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Above macro is really working. Thank you so much. You may find error at line 6. change it to set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").

Comment: This works fantastically, however in a larger scenario, it doesn't output all of the fitting criteria. Here's a screenshot of a more accurate example (I can't show the real datasheet) of what's happening.
End goal is that if column C has a non-blank cell in it, it outputs that row.
[link](https://i.imgsafe.org/6393aab069.png)

Comment: Alright I figured out what I was doing wrong. In line 16 `If ws.Cells(i, "A") <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then`, I should have had it changed to:
`If ws.Cells(i, "A") <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "A") <> "" Then`. Cross checked it on my datasheet and everything checks out. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: `If ws.Cells(i,"A") <> "" And ws.Cells(i,"A") <> "" Then` is the same as `If ws.Cells(i,"A") <> "" Then`. They are the same argument, you don't need to pass the same one twice. It should work for large data but another way you could go about this code, based off your pic and looking at column A, your code could have also been `If ws.Cells(i,"A") = "yes" Then` , you're results wold be a lot more specific and work only if a cell value was yes, leaving all the other options to put in blank cells, null, no N, etc

Comment: Right, I can't  believe I didn't see that! Thank you. Also, I would go for the `="yes"` option but in my "Fits both" column in the live datasheet, it's actually a primary key column, so every value is different. So a `<>""` is a bit easier I feel.